Invalid heap pointer
I'm practicing the implementation of Linked list code. so I write the code:
file LinkedList.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"
int main(void) {
    //initialize
    struct Node myNode = { 10,NULL };
    List head = &myNode;
    insert(20, head, head);
   
    makeEmpty(head);
   
    return 0;
}

file function.h
//this is the statement of the Linkedlist
#ifndef _FUNCTION_H
#define _FUNCTION_H
struct Node;

//pointer to the strcut Node
typedef struct Node* PtrToNode;
typedef PtrToNode List;
typedef PtrToNode Position;

struct Node
{
    //a struct pointer that point to next struct
    int element;
    //body
    Position Next;
    /* data */
};


//清空整张链表
List makeEmpty(List L);
//判断链表是否为空
int isEmpty(List L);
int isLast(Position p, List L);
Position Find(void* x, List L);
void insert(int x, List L, Position P);

#endif /*_function_h*/




file List.c
#include "function.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
List makeEmpty(List L) {
    Position cur = L;
    Position next;
    while (cur!= NULL) {
        next = cur->Next;
        free(cur); 
        cur = next;
    }
    cur = NULL;
    next = NULL;
    //这里c是copy by value 所以改变那个指针，如果不赋值的话
    //就是用void的话，不会将原来的指针改变。
    L = NULL;
    return L;
}

//right
int  isEmpty(List L) {
    return L->Next == NULL;
}

int isLast(Position P, List L) {

    //判断P在不在List里
    List cur = L;
    while (cur->Next != P) {
        cur = cur->Next;
    }
    if (cur == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "there is no P in the  list L\n");
        return  -1;
    }

    if (P->Next == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

void insert(int x, List L, Position P) {
    Position tmpCell;
    tmpCell = (Position)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (tmpCell == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"out of the space!\n");
    }
    tmpCell->element = x;
    tmpCell->Next = P->Next;
    P->Next = tmpCell;
}

but when I run the code , I get the fault that : invalid heap pointer , so why
,and when I write head->Next as the parameter in the function "makeEmpty" ,it can run ,but why, in my program , "head" point to the first struct, so head->Next should point to the second struct. I'm really puzzled.

You really shouldn't be hiding pointers behind a typedef. It makes the code much harder to read and maintain, and is therefore widely recognized as bad practice.

I wrote following the format of the book 'Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in c', thank you for your advice

Your head pointer struct Node myNode = {10, NULL} is a stack variable and can't be pass to free().
One easy solution for that is to create a function to init a new Node:
PtrToNode
create_node(int x)
{
    PtrToNode tmp_node;

    tmp_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (tmp_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"out of the space!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    tmp_node->element = x;
    tmp_node->Next = NULL;
    return tmp_node;
}

After you can init your List with the new node:
int
main(void) {
    //initialize
    List my_list = NULL;
    
    my_list = create_node(10);
    insert(20, my_list , my_list);
    makeEmpty(my_list);
    return 0;
}


thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!! have a good day. and I want to use "牛逼" to express my gratitude

TL;DR: Try to follow the life cycle of your head variable.
Long version:
The head of your list is a pointer to a local variable of main:
    struct Node myNode = { 10,NULL };
    List head = &myNode;

Nevertheless, you try to free it:
    makeEmpty(head);

The first time you enter the makeEmpty() function, cur will be equal to head and free(cur) will fail as head is the address of a variable on the stack, not an address obtained via malloc().

thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!! have a good day. and I want to use "牛逼" to express my gratitude

As other answers point out, you cannot free() objects that were not allocated by malloc() or similar functions.
One limitation of the insert function is that it does not support insertion at the head of the list. That could be supported by changing it to insert at the head of the list when P is NULL. It would also need to return the new head of the list. Here is a possible implementation:
In function.h:
List insert(int x, List L, Position P);

In List.c:
List insert(int x, List L, Position P) {
    Position tmpCell;
    tmpCell = (Position)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (tmpCell == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"out of the space!\n");
    }
    tmpCell->element = x;
    if (P == NULL) {
        tmpCell->Next = L;
        L = tmpCell;
    }
    else {
        tmpCell->Next = P->Next;
        P->Next = tmpCell;
    }
    return L;
}

The revised function may be used to create all the elements of the list…
In LinkedList.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"
int main(void) {
    List head = insert(10, NULL, NULL); // insert to empty list
    insert(20, head, head); // insert after first element of list
    head = insert(0, head, NULL); // insert at beginning of list
   
    makeEmpty(head);
   
    return 0;
}

